# How to used grep to match exact words

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have an list/array in zsh which is `house=$(cat corrected_inhouse_list.txt)`

Containing:

```
N-METHYL-L-GLUTAMIC ACID
L-GLUTAMIC ACID
CREATINE
L-PROLINE
CREATINE PHOSPHATE
L-VALINE
L-TYROSINE
L-KYNURENINE
L-PHENYLALANINE
PHENYLETHANOLAMINE
D-PANTOTHENIC ACID
L-TRYPTOPHAN
MYRISTIC ACID
```

File "metexplore_IDs_DB.tsv":

```
8:M_Lkynr   exact multimatching 1   L-KYNURENINE    CHEBI:16946 NA  NA
21:M_glu_L  exact multimatching 1   L-GLUTAMIC ACID CHEBI:16015 NA  NA
40:M_trp_L  exact multimatching 1   L-TRYPTOPHAN    CHEBI:16828 NA  NA
42:M_pro_L  exact multimatching 1   L-PROLINE   CHEBI:17203 NA  NA
50:M_phe_L  exact multimatching 1   L-PHENYLALANINE CHEBI:17295 NA  NA
56:M_creat  exact multimatching 1   CREATINE    CHEBI:16919 NA  NA
57:M_34dhphe    exact multimatching 1   3,4-DIHYDROXY-L-PHENYLALANINE (L-DOPA)  CHEBI:15765 NA  NA
61:M_tyr_L  exact multimatching 1   L-TYROSINE  CHEBI:17895 NA  NA
63:M_val_L  exact multimatching 1   L-VALINE    CHEBI:16414 NA  NA
94:M_Lkynr  exact multimatching 1   L-KYNURENINE    CHEBI:16946 NA  NA
95:M_5oxpro exact multimatching 1   5-OXO-L-PROLINE CHEBI:18183 NA  NA
107:M_4hpro_LT  exact multimatching 1   4-HYDROXY-L-PROLINE CHEBI:18095 NANA
171:M_pcreat    exact multimatching 1   PHOSPHOCREATINE CHEBI:17287 NA  NA
191:M_pnto_R    exact multimatching 1   D-PANTOTHENIC ACID  CHEBI:7916  NANA
211:M_pcreat    exact multimatching 1   CREATINE PHOSPHATE  CHEBI:17287 NANA
237:M_35diotyr  exact multimatching 1   3,5-DIIODO-L-TYROSINE   CHEBI:15768 NANA
315:M_ttdca exact multimatching 1   MYRISTIC ACID   CHEBI:28875
```

And I want to use grep to match this words on a file. The Problem is what one can see in the picture, grep also captures words that contain but not start with my word of interes.

I've tried:

```
for i in ${house[*]}; do grep -n -E "^\s*\{$i}\>" metexplore_IDs_DB.tsv; done
for i in ${house[*]}; do grep -n -E -w "\<$i" metexplore_IDs_DB.tsv; done 
for i in ${house[*]}; do grep -n -E "(^|\t)$i" metexplore_IDs_DB.tsv; done
```

[image]

What can I do to  achieve my goal? the desired output would be without lines 57, 95, 107 and 237.

Comment: `-` is a non-word character. So all the buit-in methods for matching words will treat `L-PHENYLALANINE` as a whole word in `3,4-DIHYDROXY-L-PHENYLALANINE`.

Comment: I've read that there're are problems with hyphenated words, I didn't know why. After I want to get the first column on the image; for example M_Lkynr of all matches with: cut -d \t -f 1. Line number is there only for explanation purpose.

Comment: I've tried all possible greps and i've lost my hope

Comment: Just tested it, it works, unless you're not dealing with a TSV

Comment: `grep -E $'(^|\t)'"L-PROLINE"$'(\t|$)'` will match exactly  `L-PROLINE` in a field of a TSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're always matching field 4. So `awk` would be a better solution, since you can simply do an exact match with the whole field:

```
for i in "${house[@]}"; do
    awk -F'\t' -v i="$i" '$4 == i' metexplore_ID.tsv
done
```

Don't forget the quotes around `${house[@]}`; otherwise elements like `L-GLUTAMIC ACID` will be treated as two different words to match.

You can also avoid creating the array and looping by loading `corrected_inhouse_list.txt` directly into an `awk` array:

```
awk -F'\t' -v i="$i" '
    NR == FNR {houses[$0]++; next} 
    $4 in houses' corrected_inhouse_list.txt metexplore_ID.tsv
```

Comment: the first one did not work, neither threw an error

Comment: I just realized that `exact multimatching 1` is a single field, not three fields. So the field to match is `$3`.

Comment: no, no, you're right. The data set look like this: ```M_Lkynr \t exact multimatching \t 1 \t L-KYNURENINE```

Comment: If there's a space around the tabs, add that to the `-F` option. I've updated the answer.

Comment: And from your comment I now see that it's field 4.

Comment: there's not space, was to make it more human readable. What I do not understand is where goes the ouput or why it does not show an error. I've jus tried field 4 but nothing happened

Comment: Why would it show an error? That would only happen if you have a syntax error in the script. There's no error for not finding any matches.

Comment: ah ok, thank you; I do not have matches

Comment: I just tested the second version and it worked

Comment: I had an extra quote, I noticed that when testing and fixed it above.

Comment: You also had the wrong filename in your scripts. `metexplore_IDs_DB.tsv` should be `metexplore_ID.tsv`

Comment: oh yes, the second one worked! thank you for that and to catch my mispelling in the tsv file.

Answer (score 0):

You may comside this `awk` that builds regex for each entry from your list and then searches that regex **anywhere** in the csv file:

```sh
awk '
NR == FNR {
   kw[ "(^|[[:blank:]])" $0 "([[:blank:]]|$)" ]
   next
}
{
   for (w in kw)
      if ( $0 ~ w ) {
         print
         next
      }
}' corrected_inhouse_list.txt metexplore_ID.tsv

i8:M_Lkynr   exact multimatching 1   L-KYNURENINE    CHEBI:16946 NA  NA
21:M_glu_L  exact multimatching 1   L-GLUTAMIC ACID CHEBI:16015 NA  NA
40:M_trp_L  exact multimatching 1   L-TRYPTOPHAN    CHEBI:16828 NA  NA
42:M_pro_L  exact multimatching 1   L-PROLINE   CHEBI:17203 NA  NA
50:M_phe_L  exact multimatching 1   L-PHENYLALANINE CHEBI:17295 NA  NA
56:M_creat  exact multimatching 1   CREATINE    CHEBI:16919 NA  NA
61:M_tyr_L  exact multimatching 1   L-TYROSINE  CHEBI:17895 NA  NA
63:M_val_L  exact multimatching 1   L-VALINE    CHEBI:16414 NA  NA
94:M_Lkynr  exact multimatching 1   L-KYNURENINE    CHEBI:16946 NA  NA
191:M_pnto_R    exact multimatching 1   D-PANTOTHENIC ACID  CHEBI:7916  NANA
211:M_pcreat    exact multimatching 1   CREATINE PHOSPHATE  CHEBI:17287 NANA
315:M_ttdca exact multimatching 1   MYRISTIC ACID   CHEBI:28875
```